# Identifying objects, for dummies

Tags: astronomy

If I'm a tyro and have a latitude, longitude, time, date, height from the horizon, and compass direction, what means can I use for identifying what I see there?

Realize that, as a tyro, I don't have any astronomy books or programs, and don't want to buy any; I might download a free program for my occasional inquiries about the sky, but would prefer a Web site.

Answer (score 5):

As today phones are becoming smarter and smarter I would recommend something like [Google Sky Map](http://www.google.com/mobile/skymap/) Android application. It takes geographical info from your GPS or settings and shows you a superimposed sky map on the screen taking into account your hand movements. Is so intuitive that I certainly sound like a Google salesman doing a pitch. Check yourself some videos on youtube.

And is free. :)

Comment: Cool! +1. Shame I don't have a smartphone.

Comment: that my friend is just a question of time.

Answer (score 2):

For satellites and other manmade nits and pieces, that is, very bright and fast moving then [Heavens-Above](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heavens-Above) is a great place to begin looking for clues.

For more 'everyday' objects, such as planets and stars, I have always found [Your Sky](http://www.fourmilab.ch/yoursky/) very useful.

Both require a certain knowledge of celestial coordinates and your own latitude and longitude, etc, which you say you can provide. Both are fairly comprehensive but quite technical and will take a little time to learn!

Comment: +1; thank you very much. Attempting to answer [my previous question seeking the identification of a single very bright object](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/1814) using these sites, I find that Heavens Above is very helpful; Your Sky was good, too, once I adjusted it to show only low-magnitude objects. As you say, though, I'll need to learn more about the options on either site (especially Your Sky) to make the most of it.

Comment: I should note that the link in my previous comment here is no longer live. I mean, it still links to something, but no longer to the page it used to link to.

Answer (score 1):

[Stellarium](http://stellarium.org) is great for these purposes. It's free and runs on both Widows, Mac and Linux, and is very easy to learn to use.